# Property for UISplitViewController to extend top and bottom

Tags: ios, storyboard

I inherited this project and I'm not sure what's going on here (never used a UISplitViewController).

In the storyboard, I see the Master view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController. If I click on the UITableView, the blue extends the whole screen.

[image]

But when I run it on an X, there's a gap at the top.

[image]

Is there a Storyboard setting somewhere or something I should look for in code? I do not see any constraints in code or in the storyboard that has the storyboard inset this much from the notch. It looks fine on non-notch devices including ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue earlier, For me set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` worked.

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: where do you set this?

Comment: @Crystal set it in viewDidLoad

Comment: bummer, didn't work for me :-\. I tried the newer api as well `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` and I still see that gap there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project contains launch images for all the device sizes or uses a launch storyboard instead.